# What's the proper way to write a switch statement in a React function component for rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components

My understanding is that a React *function component* does not have a `render()` function. It uses `return()`.

Currently, I'm doing:

```
if (showAll) {
  return ( 
    <Top />
    <Middle />
    <Bottom />
  )
} else if (dontShowMiddle) {
  return (
    <Top />
    <Bottom />
  )
}
....
```

I want to re-use some of this code. I know how to do this in class components (within `render()`, but not in function components.

If I wanted to do a switch statement within that `return()`, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can do everything you did inside `render()` method in class-base component with your JSX code.
You can use inline ternary operator, logic AND or logic OR operator or you can combine it using variables in your code:
You can see all three ways to do that in the example below:

```
function MyComponent () {
  let somePart = null;
  if (condition) {
    somePart = <Third />;
  }
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Top />
      {showAll && <Middle />}
      {showConditionally ? <First /> : <Second />}
      {somePart}
      <Bottom />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: in your example `somePart = <Third />`, what if it's not one neat component? What if it's several things (e.g. `<div><p><a>.....</div>`)?

Comment: As JSX is basically javascript, that will be replaced with [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html), you always have to have a root element, or you can return it as array. Remember, each element of the array should have a unique key property.
So it couldBe `somePart = [<Third key="third"/>, <Fourth key="fourth"/>];`

Comment: `{somePart}` is giving me `null[object Object]` when I try your exact example

Comment: In the example above there is no condition variable defined, showAll and showConditionally . You should add them so example will work correctly

Comment: thanks. is there any way to do `+=` operator instead of just assignment (`somePart =...`)?

Comment: Think of the JSX as javascript. so you cannot do += as all JSX code will be replaced with React.createElement by your preprocessor (not sure that I am using correct word here), https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html. So you can have "HTML snippets " with one root only there, so += cannot be performed, only push, if you gone store your items in the array